# Where can I find if the Visual C++ components or the Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools are installed in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

I guess I may be getting into trouble for asking ironically obvious questions. I had found the place that shows where things are installed on Visual Studio 2015 in 2016, but now I can't remember where it is. I see instructions of how to check using the command line, although I saw a nifty place that showed me which components were installed somewhere in the toolbars on top in 2016. Funny.

Comment: Steps 1 through 3 in this answer should get what you are after: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36046681/4581301

Comment: C++ is definitely already installed which is visible by creating an empty project or looking in Options. Maybe things have changed after ending the trial version and as with life everything changes.

Comment: Have you looked at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 1X.0\VC\bin` where `1X.0` is the version you're looking for .. `cl.exe` is the VC++ command line build tool, there's also `link.exe` and some others

Comment: Should be somewhere in registry.