# Visual studio 2017 - error MSB6006: “CL.exe” exited with code -107374515 xyz.exe is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: c++

I installed vs2017 three times but it still won't work. do you have any idea how can i make it work? I have to specifically work with visual studio 2017.

Comment: When does this error happen?

Comment: Kinda sounds like a build step is failing cause it can't find the program to run for that step.

Comment: C++ support s an optional add-on in Visual Studio 2015 and newer.  Make sure you have selected C++ support when installing. [You can add C++ support to Visual Studio 2015 through Programs and Features in the Control Panel.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36045572/i-have-installed-the-visual-studio-2015-but-there-is-no-c-project) I expect you can do similar with Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: I installed the add-on but and it says the same thing. Even when i am making "hello world " project is doing the same. If i am opening a visual studio 2013 project it would compile and show the good results.. I don't understand what is missing so is it making it say" .exe is not recognized as a command"